# Framework/Algorithms/Library for server side estimation/recognition of audio file similarity?

Tags: android, audio, sound-recognition

I want to implement an android app which compares recorded audio files with our sound database and reports a similiarity metric. The app will work somehow like Shazam but is matched against our database audio files. Can anyone point me to an open source project which implements adequate algorithms to do the sound recogognition/comparision on our server ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio hashing is used to do such comparison. Here is a technical paper that addresses some of the challenges of audio hashing: http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2004/defevent/papers/cr1091.pdf

There are technologies that can be licensed for such purposes from companies like http://www.gracenote.com/

Comment: Thanks i'll look into the paper! Is there really no open source implementation for this? I'm going to google it...

Comment: do u expect this to work as a recorder application or system wide ?